# get one of each item from array javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array with objects. One of the objects properties is "position". Another is "player_name". There are many players and only 8 unique positions. I want to go through the array and grab the first player for each position and move it to a new array. In the end, I should have a new array with a total of 8 players, each with a unique position.

Here's my code:

```
// Sample Object: { "name": "Frank Johnson", "position": "C", "cnx": "17" }

function compare(a,b) {
  if (parseFloat(a.cnx) < b.cnx)
    return -1;
  if (parseFloat(a.cnx) > b.cnx)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

var sorted = array.sort(compare);
var new_array = []
sorted.forEach(function (i) {
  if (i.position === "1B" ) {
    new_array.push(i)
    // How do I make it stop looking for 1B's at this point??
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand the desired behavior.

Comment: Your code only looks for position `"1B"`. When it stops looking for that, what should it do instead?

Comment: There are over 300 players in the array. There are 8 unique positions. I am sorting the array by the "cnx. and then want to grab the top 8 players at each position. Because when I sort them a lot of players will have the same position. I dont understand how i should approach this issue.

Comment: @sails4life can you please create valid example? And if possible a JSFiddle? Where is the `array` created for you to sort?

Comment: Yes i am reworking and will post it soon

Comment: @sails4life, OK do it and send me a comment and I'll try to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a map of the positions that you have encountered in the array, and add each object that's not in the map:

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (parseFloat(a.cnx) < b.cnx)
    return -1;
  if (parseFloat(a.cnx) > b.cnx)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

array.sort(compare);
var new_array = [];
var positions = {};
array.forEach(function (i) {
  if (!(i.position in positions)) {
    positions[i.position] = 1;
    new_array.push(i);
  }
});
```

---

To get multiple players from any position, you can use the map items as counters and put initial values for specific positions:

```
array.sort(compare);
var new_array = [];
var positions = { OF: 3 };
array.forEach(function (i) {
  if (!(i.position in positions)) {
    positions[i.position] = 1;
  }
  if (positions[i.position] > 0) {
    positions[i.position]--;
    new_array.push(i);
  }
});
```

(You can also use that to omit a position, for example `{ OF: 3, C: 0 }`).

Comment: Very elegant. What if I need 3 of just one of the positions? For example, I need 3 "OF" only. One of each of the others.

Comment: @sails4life: I added an example for that above.

Answer (score 0):

Using the very popular [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library:

Assuming you have an array of objects such as:

```
var data = [
  { "name": "Player 1", "position": "C", "cnx": "17" },
  { "name": "Player 2", "position": "B", "cnx": "17" },
  { "name": "Player 3", "position": "B", "cnx": "17" }
];
```

You can get the first player by position with:

```
_.mapValues(_.groupBy(data, 'position'), _.first);
```

Output:

```
{
  "C": {
    "name": "Player 1",
    "position": "C",
    "cnx": "17"
  },
  "B": {
    "name": "Player 2",
    "position": "B",
    "cnx": "17"
  }
}
```

If you want it in array format, you can use:

```
_.values(_.mapValues(_.groupBy(x, 'position'), _.first))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Player 1",
    "position": "C",
    "cnx": "17"
  },
  {
    "name": "Player 2",
    "position": "B",
    "cnx": "17"
  }
]
```